# Xcode 4.3.1 copies ALL the resources every time I run the project on the device

Tags: xcode, compilation, xcode4.2

I just moved to Lion and the same project compiled on Snow Leopard (and the relative previous version of Xcode) and didn't have such a problem.
Now every time I run the project it complies it all from scratch (sources, assets and stuff).
Considering that my project has quite a huge amount of assets (most of them are pngs), it takes forever even on my late 2010 Mac Pro (something like 3/4 min per compile).

This issue is making me waste a ton of time.

If anyone has already faced this problem in the past and has a solution I'd be very grateful to him.

Thanks!

Comment: This topic is a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596671/xcode-compiles-entire-project-each-time-i-run

Good luck