# Xcode always recompiles everything every time I build

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

I'm working on a `Swift 2.3` project using `Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)`, I use `Cocoapods 1.0.1` for dependency management.

I don't know what happens but every time I hit `build` or `build & run`, wether there is a modification in a file or not, the compiler will take 2-3 minutes to recompile what seems to be all the sources files of my project.

I found this thread on Apple's forum (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44406) that doesn't solve my issue (I applied `Compiler Default` settings to both my project and the `Pods` sub-project).

I have no idea what's happening and it's driving me crazy. Any lead welcome :)

Thanks!

Cyril

Comment: What about `Preprocessor` and `Optimization` settings?

Comment: Checked and project is using default settings (same as newly created project), essentially no optimizations when compiling Debug and inherited settings for preprocessor.

Comment: For `Preprocessor Macro` try setting `Debug` value to `DEBUG=1`...

Comment: Unfortunately, this setting is already there: `DEBUG=1 COCOAPODS=1`

Comment: ( Maybe as a test ) try setting optimizations on for debug ( although this isn't really want you'll want for debugging ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596671/xcode-compiles-entire-project-each-time-i-run

Comment: Already tried to use `Fastest, Smallest` in Debug to see, knowing that will actually increase building time, no change, project compiles again and again.

Comment: Apart from that I would diff compare the derived data between builds. If nothing is actually changed then maybe file a bug with Apple. Have you checked to see if this only happens when using Cocoa Pods? I'm thinking there might be something in that regard which holds the answer...